# Import Excel file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, excel, import

I have a plunker attached herewith. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/RkUCchxd6UghOTclMDFj?p=preview

I am able to import a text file properly without any errors. However, when I try to import an Excel file, it imports random alphanumeric values and unrelated data.

Can you please let me know if there is an easy way out there to import and Excel file (csv and xlsx file )?

I read online and found this document but I am not sure how it is used in JavaScript and HTML. Can anyone help?

http://psjinx.com/programming/2014/01/04/parsing-excel-workbooks-using-javascript/

```
<html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You may use js-xlsx library to parse excel file to json using javascript
[js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx)

the readme file explain how to use the library, or you may refer to the following article which talks about the library usage
[Parse and Read Excel Files (xls/xlsx) With JavaScript](http://codetheory.in/parse-read-excel-files-xls-xlsx-javascript/)

Comment: @SaDHacK- is there a easy way to import ? i am not able to understand how this js-xlsx is used

Comment: if you could provide me a jsfiddle or a plunker, it will be of great help. i can marked this answer as accepted then...