# Angular 4: How to read data from Excel?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am not able to get data from an **Excel sheet** in **Angular 4**. 
Below is my code sample.

HTML code:

```
<input id="my-file-selector" type="file" (change)="uploadData($event)" name="uploadExcel">
```

`upload.component.ts`:

```
public uploadData(event: any) : void { 
    // get data from file upload       
    let filesData = event.target.files;
    console.log(filesData[0]);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Data from FileReader in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40843218/getting-data-from-filereader-in-angular-2)

Comment: Thanks for answer is there any way though which i can read excel data as i have to bind excel records into html table

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41249187/import-excel-file-in-javascript recommends to use js-xlsx for this task

Comment: this works with javascript i need to bind excel records with html table inside my component.ts file that is typescript of angular 4

Comment: typescript is a superset of JavaScript you can use it in your angular 4 project

Comment: js-xlsx is a fork of xlsx https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx which has its own type definitions in the package. So you can try it in your typescript project.

Comment: My requirement is that i have to bind my html table with uploaded excel sheet on client side and i have to use it in my component that is already written in typescript so i cant not use jquery.

I am looking for solution with that i can directly bind my html table with uploaded excel data.

I am not able to find any proper solution yet

Comment: can anyone please help as i am new in angular 4 if there is any video tutorial please send me link of that

Answer (score 44):

You should follow these 3 steps

**step 1:** import ts-xlsx
refer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-xlsx for installation

**step 2:** Using FileReader convert to arraybuffer

**step 3:** Reading the arraybuffer with XLSX and converting as workbook

**HTML CODE**

```
<input type="file" style="display: inline-block;" (change)="incomingfile($event)" placeholder="Upload file" accept=".xlsx">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" (click)="Upload()" >Upload</button>
```

**Typescript**

```
//import it

    import * as XLSX from 'ts-xlsx';

//inside export class

arrayBuffer:any;
file:File;
incomingfile(event) 
  {
  this.file= event.target.files[0]; 
  }

 Upload() {
      let fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = (e) => {
            this.arrayBuffer = fileReader.result;
            var data = new Uint8Array(this.arrayBuffer);
            var arr = new Array();
            for(var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
            var bstr = arr.join("");
            var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type:"binary"});
            var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
            var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
            console.log(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet,{raw:true}));
        }
        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.file);
}
```

Comment: import * as XLSX from 'ts-xlsx'; where i have to add this line. in component? or that page module?

Comment: in your component. basically below `import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';`

Comment: @PrabhuRithik I just need to read the excel headers only . so by using this is it possible?

Comment: Is it possible to convert the json as parse from column wise in the excel

Comment: This is skipping empty cells. Did you solve this ? https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/50

Comment: This package has been deprecated what can i do is any another option

Comment: @PavanHukerikar you can use `import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';`

Comment: First off thanks, this code works great! 
Question. I have the data coming back in the console as you know, do you have a way to have it plot in the browser into a table?

Comment: I tried the above example code and I get error - `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` . Any body know this?

Comment: I'am just want to notify about Xlsx library link under Step 1 for deprecated library and active library link is https://www.npmjs.com/package/sheetjs, check answer => https://stackoverflow.com/a/50672884/1908296

Answer (score 40):

**You can use SheetJs/xlsx package from npm to get the data from excel as a json object in Angular / Ionic.**

Just follow these steps:

1) `npm install --save xlsx`

2) Now in your component file import xlsx

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
```

3) Now attach this function in the change event of input tag of type file

```
onFileChange(event: any) {
    /* wire up file reader */
    const target: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>(event.target);
    if (target.files.length !== 1) {
      throw new Error('Cannot use multiple files');
    }
    const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsBinaryString(target.files[0]);
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      /* create workbook */
      const binarystr: string = e.target.result;
      const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(binarystr, { type: 'binary' });

      /* selected the first sheet */
      const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[0];
      const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];

      /* save data */
      const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws); // to get 2d array pass 2nd parameter as object {header: 1}
      console.log(data); // Data will be logged in array format containing objects
    };
 }
```

You can also refer to these utils method present in xlsx to perform different operation according to your need.

https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs#utility-functions

And also during read operation you can pass these parsing options inside object

https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs#parsing-options

For any other information refer to the doc

https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs

Hope this will help you or somebody else.

Comment: This looks awesome & I referred the same for my use case. But how can we show any message in the modal/UI if the excel has duplicate rows for some column values?

Answer (score 26):

This package has been deprecated: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-xlsx

Use https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/.

And TypeScript or Angular 5: https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/tree/master/demos/typescript.

With `import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';`

Then use the steps in the answer, and it works perfectly.

Comment: This is skipping empty cells. Did you solve this ? https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/issues/50

Comment: thank you But Im getting error of buffer is not a constructor with this solution

Answer (score 4):

I've tried the file upload and below is my steps and result with both data and header,

This will also support multiple sheet within the excel sheet,

```
1.npm install --save xlsx
    
2.import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

3.HTML Code:

<input type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)">

4.Angular Typescript:

  exceltoJson = {};

  onFileChange(event: any) {
    this.exceltoJson = {};
    let headerJson = {};
    /* wire up file reader */
    const target: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>(event.target);
    // if (target.files.length !== 1) {
    //   throw new Error('Cannot use multiple files');
    // }
    const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsBinaryString(target.files[0]);
    console.log("filename", target.files[0].name);
    this.exceltoJson['filename'] = target.files[0].name;
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      /* create workbook */
      const binarystr: string = e.target.result;
      const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(binarystr, { type: 'binary' });
      for (var i = 0; i < wb.SheetNames.length; ++i) {
        const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[i];
        const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];
        const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws); // to get 2d array pass 2nd parameter as object {header: 1}
        this.exceltoJson[`sheet${i + 1}`] = data;
        const headers = this.get_header_row(ws);
        headerJson[`header${i + 1}`] = headers;
        //  console.log("json",headers)
      }
      this.exceltoJson['headers'] = headerJson;
      console.log(this.exceltoJson);
    };
  }

  get_header_row(sheet) {
    var headers = [];
    var range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(sheet['!ref']);
    var C, R = range.s.r; /* start in the first row */
    /* walk every column in the range */
    for (C = range.s.c; C <= range.e.c; ++C) {
      var cell = sheet[XLSX.utils.encode_cell({ c: C, r: R })] /* find the cell in the first row */
      // console.log("cell",cell)
      var hdr = "UNKNOWN " + C; // <-- replace with your desired default 
      if (cell && cell.t) {
        hdr = XLSX.utils.format_cell(cell);
        headers.push(hdr);
      }
    }
    return headers;
  }

5.Result
{filename: "uploadedexcel.xlsx", sheet1: Array(212), sheet2: Array(8), headers: {…}}
```

Results holds the uploaded excel name, data in the sheet1 and sheet2 and also header in the sheet1 and sheet2.

The uploaded excel sheets has sheet1 and sheet2.

Answer (score 1):

```
    readfile() {
    // You can change the file path in the assets folder
    let url = "/assets/template.xlsx";
    let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    req.onload =  (e) => {
        let data = new Uint8Array(req.response);
        let workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: "array"});
        const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, {bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array'});
        // TO export the excel file
        this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, 'X');
    };
    req.send();
}
```

You can take this code and change the path to your file; for the last line is for export it. To know more about it i suggest to visit the official doc of js-xlsx https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx

Comment: I tried the code and am able to get "data" but then I get a console error:                
   Invalid HTML: could not find <table>
    at html_to_sheet (xlsx.js:18907)

Answer (score 0):

```
/*** input in html and scope angular js */


<input type='file' ng-upload-change="uploadData" my-id="$index" ng-model='item.archivo' class="col-sm-12" base-sixty-four-input >

$scope.uploadData = function($event) {

    var files = $event.target.files;

    if (files.length > 0) {
        var fileToLoad = files[0];
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        var base64File;
        // Reading file content when it's loaded
        fileReader.onload = function(event) {
            base64File = event.target.result;


            //here your post save file-base64

            console.log(base64File)
        };
        // Convert data to base64
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
    }
}
```