# how to display excel file in angular4

Tags: javascript, excel, angular

I need to choose an Excel file by using file input type and display that file to the specific container and I need to perform some operation. I have the same thing in javascript by using Sheet.js and xlsx... I am trying to change that to Angular, but it gives an error when sheetjsw.js ImportScript. I use canvas-datagrid, dropsheet and jquery for that purpose.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: importScripts is not defined
at scripts.bundle.js:10874
```

I'd like help to obtain the result. For converting js things to Angular is better for me, because it reduces the time to create a new thing.

Comment: The Sheet.js github repo has an example of using it with Angular - see https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/tree/master/demos/angular2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read data from Excel in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47151035/how-to-read-data-from-excel-in-angular-4)

Comment: @greyBearedGeek , i tried that one,,,the file is displayed,but it is not in excel format,means not able to click rows and coulmns,it just like text document with columns and rows...so how to change it ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this [example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-read-and-export-excel-demo)

In your typescript file

```
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

onFileChange(evt: any) {
    /* wire up file reader */
    const target: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>(evt.target);
    if (target.files.length !== 1) throw new Error('Cannot use multiple files');
    const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      /* read workbook */
      const bstr: string = e.target.result;
      const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary' });

      /* grab first sheet */
      const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[0];
      const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];

      /* save data */
      this.data = <AOA>(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, { header: 1 }));
      console.log(this.data);
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(target.files[0]);
}


export(): void {
    /* generate worksheet */
    const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(this.data);

    /* generate workbook and add the worksheet */
    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');

    /* save to file */
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, this.fileName);
}
```

In your Html file

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" multiple="false" />
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of data">
            <td *ngFor="let val of row">
                {{val}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button (click)="export()">Export!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should follow these 3 steps

step 1: import ts-xlsx refer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-xlsx for installation

step 2: Using FileReader convert to arraybuffer

step 3: Reading the arraybuffer with XLSX and converting as workbook