# Is there a way to import and edit excel records in angular 6?

Tags: html, css, json, excel, angular6

I m using bulk import module in my project where i have to import records from excel, view and edit that record in my local storage.I m not getting a way, how to perform this in angular 6.

Comment: From Review: You stated something that you want to do. But you haven't actually asked a question. Have you tried to accomplish your goal? What prevented you from accomplishing it? Can you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example showing your attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this modules

1) [Link](https://www.grapecity.com/en/blogs/how-to-import-and-export-excel-spreadsheets-in-angular)

2) [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-export-xlsx)

Example of how to read excel data in [Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48549714/8612835)

Comment: Thanks @sachin shan.i have tried this module and getting my excel records in json format.How can i show this json records in table format in my html?

Comment: Solved.Thanks @sachin shan

Comment: @teju Please make the answer.