# Angular 7: Read data from excel and insert into an existing table

Tags: angular

I'm traying to insert data from excel, I used the code from this answer ,[Angular 4: How to read data from Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47151035/angular-4-how-to-read-data-from-excel) , but I only see the JSON on console. Is there any way to insert it?

Comment: Where do you want to insert the data from the excel file?

Comment: into a database, I'm using XAMPP server and PhpMyAdmin